# how can call another function after excuted multiple function in loop node js

Tags: node.js, callback, promise, async-await

Please find below code

```
function get_btc(address) {

    address_transaction(address, user_id, coin_key, deposite_txn_fee, function(callback) {

        for (var j = 0; j < callback.response.data.txs.length; j++) {
            let user_id = callback.user_id;

            //some code//
        }
    });
}

get_label_info(function(err, data) {

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        let address = data[i].address;

        deposite_model.get_coin_info(function(err, data1) {

            var coin_name = data1[0].coin_code;

            const return_functions = get_switch(coin_name);

            if (return_functions) {

                obj[return_functions](address);
            }
        })
    }
});


function all_completed() {
    console.log('all functions has been completed');
}
```

By the help of above mentioned code i want to excecute all_completed loop when all functions has been completly done.
At the initial start get_label_info function is excuted then controller go on to get_btc function.

Please help me how could i run all_completed functions after all functions completed run.

Comment: This question has an XY Problem.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem. You should describe your intentions rather than the code you wrote. What do you hope to accomplish with the above code?

Comment: You already tagged your question with "promise" and "async/await", so it seems like you know what to do? Please try to use them and post your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you are using es6, and that you know what a Promise is in that context.  In that case wrap all your callback based things in a Promise that resolves when the callback completes. Then, in your loop, push all your Promises into an array variable. Finally call Promise.all with that array as an argument and call `then` on the result to encapsulate the code you want ti run after they all complete (resolve).